# How to source a Windows batch script

Tags: cmd, working-directory

For example, I have a simple batch script `get_path.bat`

```
@echo off
echo C:\Software\dt
```

Also, I have another simple batch script `switch_dir.bat`

```
@echo off
get_path.bat > target.tmp
set /p TARGET=<target.tmp
cd %TARGET%
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is that when I invoke in `cmd.exe` the batch file `switch_dir.bat`, my current working directory changes to `C:\Software\dt`.
As of now, the scripts work but they run in a process spawned from `cmd.exe` so my current working directory stays the same. What is missing? Basically, we need Unix-like `source` or `.` here.

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Comment: A small simplification: Remove lines 2 and 3 from `switch_dir.bat` and add: `for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('get_path.bat') do set TARGET=%%A`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many possible solutions:

**Start your script with `cmd /c`:**

All you have to write in cmd is:

```
cmd /c switch_dir.bat
```

**Using `popd`/`pushd` in your batch file:**

In your `switch_dir.bat` add:

```
@echo off
pushd dir\you\want\to\remain\
get_path.bat > target.tmp
set /p TARGET=<target.tmp
cd %TARGET%
rem [code...]
popd
```

*An additional note:* A better way to find directory specified in `get_path.bat` is to use a `for /f` loop like this:

```
@echo off
pushd dir\you\want\to\remain\
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('get_path.bat') do set TARGET=%%A
cd %TARGET%
rem [code...]
popd
```